# display windows form before log in completes

Tags: c#, .net, com, office-interop

How do you display a form during user login that works similar to authentication providers like DUO? Is there a specific place to add a custom component in Windows that would work the same way?
We want to be able to display the form when the user logs into/unlocks the computer, before they are able to interact with the desktop.

We have tried using task scheduler to start a form app, but that allows the user to access the desktop.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start your app in [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)?

Comment: Kiosk mode is not an option as the app for authentication is custom.

Comment: Windows does provide the option to run custom code at login, such a component is called a "credential provider".  Squarely in C/C++ land, forget about "form" or C#. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows

Comment: Ok thank you Hans. This appears to be the next path to go down.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Windows API functions to keep the Windows form on top everything else. The [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property gets the window handle that the control is bound to.

```
IntPtr myHandle = this.Handle;
```

The value of the `Handle` property is a Windows `HWND`. If the handle has not yet been created, referencing this property will force the handle to be created.

So, you may apply Windows API functions to your form by using the handle, apply styles, keep on top and etc.

Another option which I've never tried suggest by Hans is [Credential Providers in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows). But this is relatively a new feature which works in Windows 10 and later.

Comment: We have a custom app that tries everything to lock the user into the form, but is not behaving consistently across Win 10/11 machines. Will try the Win 10 Credential Providers suggestion next.

Comment: Standard Winforms mechanisms may not provide all the features that Windows API provides.